# Postgresql ./psqlrc file directory and file don't exist on Windows 10 local machine

Tags: windows, postgresql

I was having the issue where I needed to turn off the pager to display data in the psql terminal using "`\pset pager off`". Works like a charm!

Problem is, I have to do it everytime I launch the prompt. I found this fix here - [https://pgpedia.info/p/psqlrc.html#:~:text=On%20Windows%2C%20the%20user's%20configuration,%25APPDATA%25%5Cpostgresql%5Cpsqlrc](https://pgpedia.info/p/psqlrc.html#:%7E:text=On%20Windows%2C%20the%20user%27s%20configuration,%25APPDATA%25%5Cpostgresql%5Cpsqlrc).

The problem with that fix is, the location where `./plqlrc`  is supposed to exist, doesn't. Has anyone ever dealt with this problem?

The location I am searching for the file is from this link here - [https://pgpedia.info/p/psqlrc.html#:~:text=On%20Windows%2C%20the%20user's%20configuration,%25APPDATA%25%5Cpostgresql%5Cpsqlrc](https://pgpedia.info/p/psqlrc.html#:%7E:text=On%20Windows%2C%20the%20user%27s%20configuration,%25APPDATA%25%5Cpostgresql%5Cpsqlrc).

The file says the path is `%APPDATA%\postgresql\psqlrc.conf`

I additionally ran the `pg_config --sysconfdir` and the etc folder it pointed me to also doesn't exist.

The bin and lib are setup correctly in the path as well. Not sure what's going on at this point :)

Any help would be greatly appreaciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds like a per-user configuration, `--sysconfdir` is for system configuration.

Answer (score 2):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#id-1.9.4.19.10) the file path on Windows is indeed `%APPDATA%\postgresql\psqlrc.conf`

The file is not created automatically during installation.

If you need one, then create it. It's a plain text file, so you can create it with any plain text (!) editor (Textpad, Notepad++, VSCode, Vim or even notepad).

Comment: Thanks, So I went and created it but the file isnt taking effect. I just copy/pasted what the guy had in the second url link. Is there a special step i need to take to get it to take effect?

Comment: @matt_3773 you have two identical links. But if this isn't working that that's a completely new question. Did you maybe start `psql` with the `-X` option? Or did you start it as a different user?

Comment: sorry about that, this was the link -http://mladenuzelac.blogspot.com/2016/01/psqlrc-in-windows.html - I'm running postgres as postgres user from the psql cmd prompt